# Beautify - Instance method '-initWithColor:width:radius:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Tags: ios, beautify-ios

I've imported `Beautify` but when I try this:

```
BYBorder* border = [[BYBorder alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] width:0.0 radius:5.0];
```

I get this error:

```
Instance method '-initWithColor:width:radius:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

Any idea what the problem is and how you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to import `#import <Beautify/Beautify.h>`, not just `Beautify` and also be sure to call `[[BYBeautify instance] activate];`

Comment: I now get "No visible @interface for 'BYBorder' declares the selector 'initWithColor:width:radius:'

Comment: It appears that method is a class method. You need to call `BYBorder* border = [BYBorder borderWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] width:0.0 radius:5.0];`

Comment: It's an instance method. Or at least that's how they're using it in their docs - https://github.com/beautify/beautify-ios#a-quick-introduction

Comment: Maybe the docs are outdated?  https://github.com/beautify/beautify-ios/blob/f25845d46b9e73fe61d3ac7edf367431563d5193/Pod/Classes/Theme/Styles/Properties/BYBorder.h